# Check in compile time if someClass.class is derived from a anotherClass.class?

Tags: java, runtime, compile-time, typechecking

this seems to be a newbie question, In Java, how can I check at compile time if someClass.class is derived from a anotherClass.class or at run-time if at compile time is not possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In code:

```
anotherClass.class.isAssignableFrom( someClass.class );
```

If you want to also check that the other class is a real class (and not an interface) add in a call to [`isInterface()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInterface%28%29):

```
!anotherClass.class.isInterface() && anotherClass.class.isAssignableFrom( someClass.class );
```

Example:

```
System.out.println( Number.class.isAssignableFrom( Integer.class )); // true
```

Note that `instanceof` won't work for you because you don't have instances, only classes.

Excerpt from Javadoc for [`Class.isAssignableFrom`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29):

> Determines if the class or interface represented by this Class object is either the same as, or is a superclass or superinterface of, the class or interface represented by the specified Class parameter. It returns true if so; otherwise it returns false. If this Class object represents a primitive type, this method returns true if the specified Class parameter is exactly this Class object; otherwise it returns false.

Answer (score 0):

You can check at runtime with `Class.isAssignableFrom()` if you only have classes, or the `instanceof` operator if you have instances.

As for compile time, I don't understand the question. And why wouldn't the person writing the code know *before* compile time?

Comment: -1 `instanceof` won't work because OP doesn't have instances, only classes

Comment: @Bohemian True but for completeness I believe it should be mentioned. I've reworded a little.

Answer (score 0):

Checking in runtime is straightforward as other people has already suggested.  However, it is possible to do in compile time with a little trick.

You can make use of generics to have a method like this:

```
public static <A, B extends A> void isExtends(Class<A> clazzA, Class<B> clazzB) {
    // empty
}
```

If you want to make sure someClass.class is derived from a anotherClass.class, simply put in your code:

```
isExtends(AnotherClass.class, SomeClass.class);
```

Compiler will help you to verify if SomeClass extends from AnotherClass.

(But honestly, I wonder if this is actually something useful in real life  :P )